# How to spy a CDI bean in Arquillian test

Tags: mockito, cdi, jboss-arquillian

In my former Spring development, it is easy to spy a Spring bean via `@SpyBean` or Mockito `spy` method, and do some stubbing and verifying it in the testing codes.

But when I tried to do the same steps in Arquillain test for Jakarta EE applications, it does not work as expected.

```java
@Inject CargoInspectionService cargoInspectionService;


@Test
public void testCargoWasHandled(){
    var cargoInspectionServiceSpy = spy(cargoInspectionService);
    doNothing().when(cargoInspectionServiceSpy).inspectCargo(eq(new TrackingId("AAA")));

    // some real actions.

    verify(cargoInspectionServiceSpy, atLeastOnce()).inspectCargo(any(TrackingId.class));
 
}
```

There is no interactions of mocked/spyed object at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Arquillian extension for this purpose: https://github.com/topikachu/arquillian-extension-mockito/

Assuming Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can then use the extension's `@Spy` annotation to spy on the service:

```java
@Inject @Spy CargoInspectionService cargoInspectionService;


@Test
public void testCargoWasHandled(){
    doNothing().when(cargoInspectionService).inspectCargo(eq(new TrackingId("AAA")));

    // some real actions.

    verify(cargoInspectionService, atLeastOnce()).inspectCargo(any(TrackingId.class));
 
}
```

Comment: It seems it is not active for years.

Comment: That is not uncommon for Arquillian extensions, especially simple ones. Usually they don't need much modification